# Visual Studio - Xamarin Android viewer error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4 with all updates installed running on Windows 10.  I have a Xanarin forms projects, when I try to view the Android preview screen it shows a yellow bar with an error.  You can't copy the error and there is no error in the output screen.

Any suggestion on how to diagnose the problem so I can fix it.  I have tried clean, repair, and emptying the package folders.

Attached screen shot of error since I can't copy it and don't want to type it, I goes away.

[image]

[Edit] - requested XAML, but as I said in comments, does not matter what the XAML code is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyApp.Views.PageHolder">
      <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" />
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: could you show your xaml ?

Comment: It is on all pages, even default pages just created

Comment: Is your JDK version 1.8-64bit? if not,you could set the jdk 1.8 to 64 bit version.

Comment: Java Dev Kit Location under Xamarin is set to "C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.9", release in that directory say OS_ARCH="amd64"